# How to store an object which has File object in it in MongoDB using spring-data and java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Hi I have a class called Outbox as shown below:

```
@Document(collection="outbox")
public class OutBox {

    private String fileName;
    private String id;
    private String userName;
    private File file;


    public OutBox(String fileName,String userName,File file){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public OutBox(String id,String fileName){
        this.id = id;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

I have File inside my outbox class. I know a file can be stored in mongoDB using GRIDFS. But how to store an object which has File inside it.. Please help.

Comment: Don't forget that a Java `File` object isn't an actual file on the file system - it's just an abstract path name.

Comment: Please consider that  in MongoDB storage this is very abstract. In general MongodB "does not care" what the data "type" is thrown at the field, and will just "store" it to what is believed to the the appropriate "type" ( likely Binary at the driver level, without intervention ). So it really depends on how it is ultimately presented and also the intent.